My turtle shouldn't be able to enter this box but yet it does
The goal of this code down below is essentially to make sure the turtle which can move in any direction using the arrow key cannot enter the box. I did this by making a collision method for my class shape and used simple math to ensure the turtle cannot enter the shape.
However sadly it doesn't work. The turtle can enter the shape from every direction except the bottom.
Can someone either fix my code or help me go about this in a different and easier way?
Here is my code:
import turtle
sam=turtle.Turtle()
score=turtle.Turtle()
screen=turtle.Screen()
screen.delay(0)
PEN_SIZE = 10
CURSOR_SIZE = 20
BOUNDARY = PEN_SIZE/2 + CURSOR_SIZE/2
sam.pensize(PEN_SIZE)
sam.speed('fastest')
sam.penup()
sam.goto(-400,-400)
sam.pendown()
sam.speed(0)
sam.color("blue")
screen.bgcolor("black")
class lshape4:
    def __init__(self,turtle, x, y, width, height):
        self.turtle=turtle
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    def draw(self): 
        for i in range(2):
          self.turtle.fd(self.width)
          self.turtle.rt(90)
          self.turtle.fd(self.height)
          self.turtle.rt(90)
    def collision(self, position):
        x, y = position
        left_boundary = self.x - self.width / 2
        right_boundary = self.x + self.width / 2
        bottom_boundary = self.y - self.height / 2
        top_boundary = self.y + self.height / 2

        if left_boundary <= x <= right_boundary and bottom_boundary <= y <= top_boundary:
          return True
        else:
          return False
shapes = []
shape4 = lshape4(sam,-120,-270,100,20)

sam.penup()
sam.goto(-120, -270)
sam.lt(90)
sam.pendown()
shape4.draw()

shapes.append(shape4)

j = turtle.Turtle()
j.shape('turtle')
j.color('yellow')

j.penup()
j.goto(400, -370)

def right():
  j.rt(90)

def left():
  j.left(90)

def up():
  j.forward(10)

  position = j.position()

  for shape in shapes:
     if shape.collision(position):
         j.undo()
         return

def down():
  j.bk(10)

  position = j.position()

  for shape in shapes:
     if shape.collision(position):
         j.undo()
         return
 screen.listen()
 screen.onkeypress(up, 'Up')
 screen.onkeypress(down, 'Down')
 screen.onkeypress(right, 'Right')
 screen.onkeypress(left, 'Left')


I am assuming that the box is the *boundary fields? If so why are you updating them?

line 84 screen.listen() IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level. I suggest [edit]ing the post to fix this. Collisions aside, your basic key handling setup is not ideal for real-time turtle. I suggest this approach which avoids the OS-specific keyboard retrigger delay, among other things. As for comparisons in your collision, I would avoid the Python-specific, confusing triple comparisons. Box collisions are a pretty well-established math check you can translate from just about any language into this use case.

You can also make the box a turtle and use turtle.distance. Reset the position to the last non-colliding position to resolve the collision.

If you're making a step/grid-based game like Sokoban or Snake, then you can use a grid-based collision system, (naively, but easily) a 2d list representing the collision state for each cell on the screen. Which is best sort of depends on your use case.

The orientation of the turtle when drawing the shape was incorrect, as were the calculations for the boundaries of the shape.
Below are corrections with comments:
import turtle

sam = turtle.Turtle()
score = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.delay(0)
PEN_SIZE = 10
CURSOR_SIZE = 20
BOUNDARY = PEN_SIZE / 2 + CURSOR_SIZE / 2
sam.pensize(PEN_SIZE)
sam.speed('fastest')
sam.speed(0)
sam.hideturtle()
sam.color('blue')
screen.bgcolor('black')

class LShape4:
    def __init__(self, turtle, x, y, width, height):
        self.turtle = turtle
        self.x = x  # This is the bottom left of the shape
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        # Do these calculations once
        self.left = x - BOUNDARY
        self.right = x + width + BOUNDARY
        self.bottom = y - BOUNDARY
        self.top = y + height + BOUNDARY

    def draw(self):
        # All the drawing setup should be done here.
        # Orient the turtle starting at the bottom left.
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.goto(self.x, self.y)
        self.turtle.setheading(0)  # Make sure facing the right direction to start
        self.turtle.pendown()
        for i in range(2):
            self.turtle.fd(self.width)
            self.turtle.lt(90)  # Left instead of right, so +x then +y then -x then -y is drawn.
            self.turtle.fd(self.height)
            self.turtle.lt(90)
        self.turtle.penup()

    def collision(self, position):
        x, y = position
        return self.left <= x <= self.right and self.bottom <= y <= self.top

# DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself
def check_collision(turtle):
    position = turtle.position()
    for shape in shapes:
        if shape.collision(position):
            turtle.undo()

def right():
    j.rt(90)

def left():
    j.left(90)

def up():
    j.forward(10)
    check_collision(j)

def down():
    j.bk(10)
    check_collision(j)

# Make a couple shapes
shapes = [LShape4(sam, -120, -270, 100, 20), LShape4(sam, 0, 0, 50, 100)]
for shape in shapes:
    shape.draw()

j = turtle.Turtle()
j.shape('turtle')
j.color('yellow')
j.penup()
j.goto(400, -370)

screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(down, 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(left, 'Left')

screen.mainloop()

